# How can I mock MyClass.class.getClassLoader()?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Is it possible to mock (or at least to suppress) such invocation as

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt")
```

using `PowerMock`?

Comment: create a wrapper method for this code, then mock that method?

Comment: I need to mock `getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: I been racking my brain on this and can't figure it out.  How about actually including that file as part of your test resources?

Comment: It is not the right approach. When I write unit tests I can't use any external dependencies (File System).

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

One solution (I think that it was what bayou.io meant in one of the comments) would be to abstract away the retrieval of the resource, as in:

```
public interface ResourceRetriever{
    public InputStream getResource(String location);
}

public class ClassloaderResourceRetriever implements ResourceRetriever{
    @Override
    public InputStream getResource(String location){
        this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream();
    }
}

public class MyClassThatNeedsSomeResources {
    private final ResourceRetriever resourceRetriever;

    public MyClassThatNeedsSomeResource (ResourceRetriever resourceRetriever){
        this.resourceRetriever = resourceRetriever;
    }

    public void myMethodThatNeedsSomeResource(){
        InputStream resource = resourceRetriever.getResource("foo");
        // use your newly retrieved resource
    }
}
```

Thanks to this, you can easily mock out the retriever, as in

```
...
@Test
public void resourceShouldBeRetrieved() {
    // given
    ResourceRetriever r = Mockito.mock(ResourceRetriever.class);
    ByteArrayInputStream fakeResource = new ByteArrayInputStream("foobar".getBytes());
    when(r.getResource("foo").thenReturn(fakeResource);

    MyClassThatNeedsSomeResources c = new MyClassThatNeedsSomeResources(r);


    // when
    c.myMethodThatNeedsSomeResource();

    // then
    verify(r).getResource("foo");
}
```

This abstraction will also make your code more reusable, as you can easily implement a ResourceRetriever that works with Spring [Resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html), [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)s, [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) or other variations.